# ReactJS) how to get data with XMLHttpRequest from PHP and render that data inside sibling component

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux

I am currently developing a ReactJS web application.

No JQuery is used.

When ReactJS triggers onTouchEnd event, ReactJS will send XMLHttpRequest to my php server. PHP will loop through MYSQL database. After that, if looping through database was successful, PHP will send HTML data to javascript AND! I WILL RENDER THESE HTML DATAS INSIDE SIBLING COMPONENT.

```
export default class ItemList extends React.Component{
state={
    isScrolled:''
}
handleClick = (e)=>{
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    console.log('click '+e.target.id);
}
handleTouchStart = (e)=>{
    console.log('touch start '+e.currentTarget.id);
}
handleTouchMove = (e)=>{
    console.log('touch move'+e.target.id);
    this.setState({
        isScrolled:'scrolled'
    })
}
handleTouchEnd = (e)=>{
    const continent = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-continent');
    if(this.state.isScrolled=='scrolled'){
        console.log('nothing happens');
    }else{
        console.log('event worked');
        ajaxRequest(e.currentTarget.className,continent);
    }
    this.setState({
        isScrolled:''
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <section id="Main">
            <Continents 
                onClick={this.handleClick} 
                onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}
                onTouchMove={this.handleTouchMove}
                onTouchEnd={this.handleTouchEnd}
            />
            <Countries/>
        </section>
    )
 }
}

class Continents extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div className="items">
            <div id="Continent1" {...this.props} data-continent="Europe" className="continents">
                <figure>    
                    <img src="img/london.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>EUROPE</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="Continent2" {...this.props} data-continent="Asia" className="continents" >
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/korea.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>ASIA</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="Continent3" {...this.props} data-continent="North America" className="continents">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/grandcanyon.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>NORTH AMERICA</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="Continent4" {...this.props} data-continent="South America" className="continents">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/brazilRio.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>SOUTH AMERICA</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="Continent5" {...this.props} data-continent="Africa" className="continents">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/africaWild.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>AFRICA</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="Continent6" {...this.props} data-continent="Oceania" className="continents">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/aukland.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>OCEANIA</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class Countries extends React.Component{
render(){
    return('')
}
}
```

this is ajaxRequest function

```
export default function ajaxRequest(e,value){
let xhr;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if(typeof(e.target)!='undefined'){
    switch(e.target.className){
        case 'search':
        xhr.open('get','//localhost:80/ReactStudy/travelReduxApp/public/server/search.php?search=' + value,true);
    }
}else{
    switch(e){
        case 'continents':
            xhr.open('get','//localhost:80/ReactStudy/travelReduxApp/public/server/itemList.php?continent='+value ,true);
    }
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data){
    switch(xhr.status){
        case 200:
            const text = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(text);
    }
}
if(xhr.readyState===XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    xhr.abort();
}
xhr.send();
}
```

What I get in console.log in xhr.onreadystatechange

```
<div>England</div><div>Italy</div><div>Germany</div><div>Sweden</div><div>Russia</div><div>Czech Republic</div><div>Poland</div><div>Greece</div><div>Netherlands</div><div>Spain</div><div>Portugal</div><div>France</div>
```

what should I do if I want render all these divs in Countries component? 
Should I use redux in my case?
What is the best way?

Sorry for my poor english. Not a native english speaker.

Comment: Where does your ajaxRequest method live? Is it in scope so that you can simply put the results into the state?

Comment: @ageoff Sadly, it is on separate file. I put ajax method on separate module because I use my ajax call multiple times for multiple uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Forget about:**

- xhr, use fetch or axios (few lines of code instead this mess);
- **returning html from php**, return json array;

After fetching save json result in state (using setState) and pass to `<Countries/>`

```
<Countries list={this.state.countries} />
```

and inside `<Countries/>` render use map

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.list.map( (country,idx) => (
         <div key={idx}>{country}</div>
      ) )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**You can render it as div, li, button, assign event handlers, sort, filter** ... whatever you need w/o calling php again.

It's a **simple flow** (fetch json, setState, render) and there're multum tutorials about this, usually rendering data in the same component, passing loaded data to child works almost the same (above).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to have the backend give you the data rather than the markup.

However, you can still add this through a react property called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. [Keep in mind this comes with some security issues from XSS](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

PD: If you're just learning react, DON'T USE REDUX. It will overwhelm you and is usually avoidable (specially for smaller apps).

Comment: Ok thanks. Understood your answer. But regardless what type of data does php send, my problem is the same. Somehow ajax need to send all datas to sibling component.  I am not sure if it is a good idea, but I think maybe maybe somehow make these datas as state in ItemList component and pass that to Countries component. But not sure ..

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question before.
But you're making the request in `ItemList`, you should be able to save it (in a state for example) and pass it down to the Countries component as props, right?
I don't know if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is handle the ajax request in an async method and wait for the result. Then you will have it locally so you can display or pass it anywhere you need it... something like this:

```js
state = {countries:''}
getRequestData = async () => {
  let result = await ajaxRequest(e.currentTarget.className,continent);
  this.setState({countries:result})
}

handleTouchEnd = (e)=>{
    const continent = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-continent');
    if(this.state.isScrolled=='scrolled'){
        console.log('nothing happens');
    }else{
        console.log('event worked');
        getRequestData()
    }
    this.setState({
        isScrolled:''
    })
}
```